# Problema com listas - Python

Tags: python, lista

Não consigo fazer:

> 9. Foram anotadas as idades e alturas de 5 alunos. Faça um Programa que determine quantos alunos com mais de 13 anos possuem altura
>      inferior à média de altura desses alunos.

Código Final:

```
idadeAlunos = [12,13,13,15,16]
alturaAlunos = [1.70,2.0,1.40,1.55,1.70]
x = 0

for i in range(len(alturaAlunos)):
    x += alturaAlunos[i]
x = x/len(alturaAlunos)

contador = 0

for j in range(len(idadeAlunos)):
    if idadeAlunos[j] >= 13 and alturaAlunos[j] < x:
        contador += 1
print(contador)
```

Comment: Comece estudando algoritmos. É visível que você tem muita dificuldade em estruturar qualquer lógica desejada. Depois, calcule a média das alturas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faça as coisas passo a passo. Tente isolar os problemas.

Primeira coisa, o problema diz que será necessário usar a media das alturas, portanto, primeira coisa, calcule a media das alturas e armazene em uma variavel.

Apos isso, vc precisa iterar sobre a primeira lista (de idades) e pra cada elemento iterado verificar se ele eh > que 13 (if elemento > 13: ....)

Feito isso basta utilizar o indice do elemento iterado para achar sua altura correspondente e verificar se a mesma eh menor que a media. Para encontrar a altura correspondente vc pode usar `alturaAlunos[idadeAlunos.index(elemento)]` onde elemento sera o elemento sendo iterado no laço.

Ultima dica, use um laço `for` para iterar sobre a lista `idadeAlunos`.

Poste seu codigo caso tenha conseguido resolver o problema, se não conseguir, poste para que eu possa ajudar a resolver.

Sempre que estiver trabalhando com Python (ou qualquer outra linguagem) pesquise na internet funções que possam te auxiliar, quase sempre terá uma coisa que faz o que vc quer em apenas uma linha em Python.

Exemplo: vc declarou uma variavel e fez um for loop para calcular a soma das alturas. Isso poderia ser resolvido jogando no google "como eu calculo a soma dos elementos de uma list em python".

Resposta: `sum(nome_da_lista)`

No seu caso: `media = sum(nome_da_lista)/len(nome_da_lista)`

Comment: Modifiquei meu código acima, tinha feito isso da outra vez, e travo nessa parte.

Comment: Legal, deu pra perceber que vc está tentando e até está no caminho certo. No seu ultimo loop, vc esta iterando sobre a lista idadeAlunos e atribuindo o indice de cada aluno na variavel `j` a cada iteração. Como as listas são relacionadas por posição, vc pode fazer o seguinte: no seu comando if, deixe ele mais "completo" para satisfazer as duas condições da seguinte forma: `if idadeAlunos[j] > 13 and alturaAlunos[j] < x: contador = contador + 1` Não esqueça de declarar a variavel contador com valor 0 fora do loop

Comment: Sim, entendo que pode ser resolvida já com funções prontas. Mas é que preciso fazer com estruturas de repetição, pois é o que vai cair na minha prova de hoje, hahaha

Comment: Então galera, travei nessa parte, definitivamente... Sei o que tem que fazer, mas não sei o que usar pra executar... Código acima

Comment: Kkkkkkkkk, esquece galera, já consegui, tava de cabeça quente, obrigado à todos!

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro você calcula a média de altura:

```
altura_alunos = [1.70, 2.0, 1.40, 1.55, 1.70]
media_altura = sum(altura_alunos) / float(len(altura_alunos))
```

Este laço está correto. Só precisa colocar toda a lógica junta:

```
for j in range(len(idade_alunos)):
    if idade_alunos[j] >= 13:
        if altura_alunos[j] <= media_altura:
            x += 1
```

Comment: Nesse caso, o `float` no comprimento da lista seria desnecessário, não? Visto que `sum` já retornará um `float`, estaria dividindo um `float/int`, que é válido.

Comment: Só por ortogonalidade de operador. Sim, pode ser tirado.